# How to include hibernate jars into WEB-INF

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, jakarta-ee

I have a J2EE project using Hibernate and Maven.

The hibernate part works fine and I can do what I need from a few classes.
However, when I try to use Hibernate tools from a servlet, I get :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [servlets.ImproServletTest] in context with path [/ImproDB] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
```

I suppose this points to hibernate classes that are not available in WEB-INF.
I assume that I need to hard copy the jars in WEB-INF directory to get this sorted.

However, the hibernate classes were imported via Maven.
I can see them into Eclipse project explorer in :
"ProjectName/Java Resources/Libraries/Maven Dependencies".
But there does not seem to be such directories in my project workspace (I mean on my hard drive). 
Where are these jars supposed to be located on the hard drive?
What is the best practise to include them into WEB-INF hoping that this will solve my issue?

Thx in advance.

EDIT:
pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ImproDB</groupId>
  <artifactId>ImproDB</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Could i see your pom.xml and i can make appropriate treatment here

Comment: The default Maven dependency scope (i.e. no `<scope>` at all) should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your pom.xml like this and run command `mvn clean package` where your pom.xml is. This builds web application to war package and hibernate will be included also in `WEB-INF/lib` folder:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ImproDB</groupId>
  <artifactId>ImproDB</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Same mistake after having added this.

Comment: Show me your list of jars in WEB-INF\lib in your war package that you deployed on server.

Comment: There's nothing in WEB-INF\lib .
My understanding was that Maven should make the necessary imports after the change that you suggeted in pom.xml?

Comment: To run your application in JEE container in that case propably Tomcat you need to build war package. For that i posted pom.xml from which you can build that war that includes `hibernate-core` jar. So my another question how do you run this application now without mandatory libs that are required for that ?

Comment: Yep, I do use Tomcat for the server environnment.
So the project works fine when I call the hibernate classes from a local test class (as Maven correctly imported the jars for local use). It only fails when I call them from a servlet (server side).

Comment: So that is the problem. Tomcat doesnt know about `hibernate` unless you point him to use this jar. To make that happens you need to build war package that contains required libraries.

Comment: Are there no tools that can do it automatically that you know about?
I thought that Maven would be able to do it fine.
The bad point is that, for instance, if I want to upgrade my hibernate version for this project later, I ll have to import the newer hibernate libraries via Maven, AND then create a new uddated WAR archive afterwards.
Is that the way it works or is there a more straightforward way of proceeding?

Comment: Ho, I missed the part of your first message asking to run " mvn clean package". I have just done it.
Now I have a ImproDB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war file in ProjectName\target directory.
Also I can see the hibernate jar files into "ProjectName\target\ImproDB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib" .
However, the files don't appear in Eclipse projects explorer into WEB-INF and thus the error keeps occuring when I call the servlet. 
Should I just copy the war or the jars into ProjectName\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib ? Or is there a cleaner way ?

Comment: and I still get the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
after copying both the war file and the jar files into  ProjectName\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib.
I actually did not expect this to happen!!

Comment: How do you run your web application ?

Comment: Well I just run the servlet via eclipse using tomcat 8.

Comment: Ho I just missed to hit F5 after copying the jars.
It works fine now.
Thx so much Pawel for having guided me through this mess, I owe you one beer ;).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add servlet dependency..

`<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>`

try this

Comment: Same mistake after having added this.